# Why I have different results in browsers 'Chrome' and 'Internet Explorer'?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, protractor

I'm using protractor for e2e testing, but I have strange problem. My tests worked fine on 'Chrome', but when I choose 'Internet Explorer' some objects not found and my tests fails. Why? And what I may do with that?

Examples of failing specs:

```
describe('ps-grid-column-filter-range_spec_1.1.a', function() {

var config = browser.params;

var req = config.req_lib_filter;
require(req);

var tester_column_number = config.column_number_filter;                                         
var tester_url = config.url_filter;

var filter_field = element(by.xpath("//td[@class='ng-scope n-grid__filter']["+ tester_column_number +"]"));          
var balloon_info = $('div[class="n-balloon n-balloon_bottom_left n-balloon_can_close n-balloon_info"]');                            

beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get(tester_url);
});


it('balloon should contain text',function(){                                                
    filter_field.click();                                                                   
    browser.sleep(3000);                                                                    
    var balloon_text = (balloon_info.element(by.css('div'))).element(by.css('span'));   
    var height = balloon_info.getAttribute("style");
    expect(height).toContain("height: 50px;");                                              
    expect(balloon_text.getText()).toContain('Допустимо вводить диапазон от');              
    expect(balloon_text.getText()).toContain('Например:');                                                                               
    if (true) console.log("ps-grid-column-filter-range_spec_1.1.a : text1");      


  }); 

it('should show balloon',function(){                                                        
    filter_field.click();                                                                   
    browser.sleep(3000);                                                                    
    if (balloon_info.isPresent()) expect(balloon_info.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);            
    else expect(true).toBe(false);                                                          
    if (true) console.log("ps-grid-column-filter-range_spec_1.1.a : text2");      

}); 
 });
```

In 'Chrome' it okey, but in the 'Internet Explorer' I get an error:

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator BycssSelector("div[class="n-balloon n-balloon_bottom_left n-balloon_can_close n-balloon_info"]")
```

Comment: What version of IE, what version of protractor and webdriver? My wild guess would be that you are using selectors that don't work in IE

Comment: @maurycy IE version: 9; Protractor: 2.1.0; Webdriver: V2.45.0. But, unfortunately, I can't change browser version...

Comment: It's most likely css selectors

Comment: Could you please add samples of failing specs to the question description?

Comment: @Michael Radionov yep.I did it.

Answer (score 0):

With IE it's always something extra you should do to make things work.

In your case, I would try the following:

- add an Explicit Wait instead of the `browser.sleep()`:

  ```
  filter_field.click(); 

  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  browser.wait(balloon_info, 5000);
  ```
- click the filter through javascript:

  ```
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", filter_field);
  ```